# NSUserDefaults doesn't save my values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I use this code to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"vruch" forKey:@"nastoikaIP"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and this code to load:

```
NSString* automanual = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                         valueForKey:@"nastroikaIP"];

if ([automanual isEqualToString:@"vruch"]) {
    autovruch.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
   [self obnovittext];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use the method [`setValue:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-BABEHECF) (from the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol) but [`setObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDHAGB) (from the `NSUserDefaults` class) to store the string.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"vruch" forKey:@"nastroikaIP"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can retrieve the string using the method [`stringForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHEAEAF)

```
NSString* automanual = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"nastroikaIP"];
```

Finally, note that it is generally better to define constants for the keys you use in `NSUserDefaults` to avoid any mistyping errors, which may be hard to debug when they happen.

**Edit**

It looks like you already did a mistyping error `nastoikaIP` != `nastroikaIP`. Notice the missing/extra `r` letter.

Comment: i copied your code to my project, but it still doesn't work for me. Is setObject only an "id" or it may be a "string"?

Comment: @HorheGarcia - Well, what I said about using constants is already happening. You set the value with the key `nastoikaIP ` and retrieve it using a different key `nastroikaIP`. I don't know what language this is, but there is either an extra `r` or a missing `r`.

Comment: @sch: Note that the methods are not called `setValue:` and `setObject:` but `setValue:forKey:` and `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

Your saving a string so you need to setObject rather than setValue

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"vruch" forKey:@"nastoikaIP"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and change it for the loading aswell

```
 NSString* automanual = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nastroikaIP"];

if ([automanual isEqualToString:@"vruch"]) {
autovruch.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[self obnovittext];
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but sorry it doesn't work for me.. seems I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try NSLog( @"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] ); to see what values and keys you are actually using.